# HTTPS redirect on sub application

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

I have an application with this domain http://abc.example.com/portal. Portal is a sub application to the main application (abc.example.com) on IIS.

I would like to redirect to https://abc.example.com/portal if anyone access it by  http://abc.example.com/portal.

I added these lines to the web.config:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
       <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true">
           <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
           <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

After this, if I call site http://abc.example.com/portal, it takes me to https://abc.example.com/ and not to https://abc.example.com/portal.

Do you guys have any idea how can I make this work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rule to:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}/{R:1}" />
```

Also, if the /example subdirectory is an application, make sure these rewrite rules are placed in that web.config and not the parent application's web.config.

Comment: I have found that this rule duplicates (and, thus, breaks) the path if accessing, for example, `http://abc.example.com/portal/someFolder/SomePage.aspx?SomeQueryString`. What worked for me was `<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />`.